# Change resource with ant build android

Tags: android, ant

I created a build.xml file with command "android update project".

Now i want build multiple version of project with difference resources. Anyone can suggest me some ideas to edit the default build.xml file was created by command.

```
<property file="local.properties" />
<property file="ant.properties" />
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>
<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

Comment: Use Android STudio with build flavors - that is what they are for. Good luck trying to do that with eclipse